# Convert Grub2 entry to Syslinux

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, syslinux

I have been trying to do it for hours now, but so far I was unable to.

I have a USB stick with grub4dos on sda1 (vfat), /boot syslinux on sda3 (ext2) and root on sda2 (btrfs). ext2 with syslinux is the boot partition.

There are two options in the menu:
1. Boot Arch on btrfs. This one works fine.
2. chainload to grub4dos (Easy2Boot) on sda1.

I had this setup working with grub2, but I now moved to syslinux, I can't get the second option to work. Here's the original working grub2 entry:

```
menuentry "Live ISOs"{
        set root='(hd0,1)'
        linux /grub.exe
}
```

Now, I tried to convert it to syslinux like so:

```
LABEL E2B
    MENU LABEL Live ISOs
    COM32 /chain.c32 hd0,1
    APPEND ntldr=/grub.exe
```

but it gives me "ERR: Coudn't read the boot file"

Also, like so:

```
LABEL E2Bb
    MENU LABEL Live ISOs
    BOOT /grldr
    APPEND root=/dev/sda1
```

but this doesn't give me even an Error. Just a screen flash and back to syslinux menu.

... and like so:

```
LABEL E2B
    MENU LABEL Live ISOs
    COM32 chain.c32
    APPEND hd0 1 grldr=/grub.exe
```

of which the result is:

```
ERR: Option 'maps' requires a sector.
```

I think the problem is showing syslinux which partition to look for the E2B boot files, and also possibly the selection of the right file (grub.exe, grldr or something else), but I am out of ideas.

Answer (score -1):

[chainload-syslinux](http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/chainload-syslinux) can help you - it has some examples

Comment: It would be best to inline the relevant information from that page into your answer (in case that website disappears, and also so we can have a minimally working answer).

Comment: I tried those combinations but with no luck. Even E2B author was unable to help me. It looks like I will have to file it under "impossible" with syslinux and go back to Grub2.